# Inconsistent ExpandableListView Positions

Tags: android, view

I have an ExpandableListView which changes it's items based on their positions in the groups. The code below works the first time the ListView is drawn but when it redraws off of something like scrolling it makes the childPosition value change. For example, if I scroll to the bottom of the list (hiding the first child) and scroll back up to the top, the getChildView will proccess the top view as the last child.

To be honest the position values are very inconsistent with what's actually on the screen. Is this a bug in Android or am I missing something here?

As an added note, when I add data to this ExpandableListView and populate the Views (using the same function) based on the groupPosition and childPosition values, the data is correct...

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) get_context().getSystemService
                (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(rowFormatID, parent, false);
    }

    if(get_elementList().get(groupPosition).size()-1 == childPosition){
        View divider = v.findViewById(R.id.divider);
        divider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (get_elementList().get(groupPosition).size() == 1)
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_card_background_white);
    else {
        if(childPosition == 0)
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_card_background_white_top);
        else if(get_elementList().get(groupPosition).size()-1 == childPosition)
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_card_background_white_bottom);
    }
    return v;
}
```

EDIT: below is the adjusted code for fixing the problem

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) get_context().getSystemService
                (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(rowFormatID, parent, false);
    }

    View divider = v.findViewById(R.id.divider);
    if(get_elementList().get(groupPosition).size()-1 == childPosition)
        divider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else //added this else
        divider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    if (get_elementList().get(groupPosition).size() == 1)
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_card_background_white);
    else {
        if(childPosition == 0)
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_card_background_white_top);
        else if(get_elementList().get(groupPosition).size()-1 == childPosition)
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_card_background_white_bottom);
        else   //also added this else
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't always setup contents of your view. You should always fully initialize all parameters that can change, because in case if `contentView != null` you get a view in unknown state (it's a recycled view from some other position in the list view)

For example, you hide `divider` only if `get_elementList().get(groupPosition).size()-1 == childPosition`, otherwise you do nothing.

The same with background - if none of the branches execute, you don't change it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The size of the list never changes (in this case it's not) so it should always be static. What exactly do I need to fully initialize?

Comment: @c0d3blooded for example write `else { divider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}` after the second `if`. And after the last nested `if`: `else v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whatever_default_background_you_have);`.

Comment: It's a bit weird having to put in those extra checks but doing so keeps a consistent LivstView. Thanks a bunch! I've updated my answer with the adjusted code.

Comment: @c0d3blooded it's not weird - unless `convertView` is null and you create a new view, `convertView` is in unknown state and you have to put it in order.